# Java game ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, eclipse, game-engine

How do I fix this error? I am trying to import a "sub- sprite sheet" into my game but am getting an arrayIndexOutOFBounds error

Source code and errors:

I'm trying to implement a 'sub-spritesheet" and I have no idea why i'm getting this out of bounds error. Here are the screens of the class where all errors occur.

```
package com.apcompsci.game.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {
private String path;
public final int SIZE;
public final int WIDTH,HEIGHT;
public int [] pixels;

public static SpriteSheet tiles = new SpriteSheet("/textures/sheets/spritesheet.png",256);
public static SpriteSheet spawn_level = new SpriteSheet("/textures/sheets/spwan_level.png",48);
public static SpriteSheet projectile_DemiGod = new SpriteSheet("/textures/sheets/projectiles/DemiGod.png",48);
public static SpriteSheet player = new SpriteSheet("/textures/sheets/player_sheet.png",95,129);
public static SpriteSheet player_down = new SpriteSheet(player, 0, 0, 1,3,32);

public SpriteSheet(SpriteSheet sheet, int x, int y, int width, int height, int spriteSize)
{
    int xx =  x*spriteSize;
    int yy = y*spriteSize;
    int w = width*spriteSize;
    int h = height *spriteSize;
    if(width == height) SIZE = width;
    else SIZE = -1;
    WIDTH = w;
    HEIGHT = h;
    pixels = new int[w*h];
    for(int y0 = 0; y0<h; y0++)
    {
        int yp = yy + y0;
        for(int x0 = 0; x0<w; x0++)
        {
            int xp = xx + x0;
            pixels[(x0+y0)*w] = sheet.pixels[(xp+yp)*sheet.WIDTH];
        }
    }

}

public SpriteSheet(String path, int size)
{
    this.path = path;
    SIZE = size;
    pixels = new int[SIZE*SIZE];
    WIDTH = size;
    HEIGHT = size;
    load();
}

public SpriteSheet(String path, int width, int height)
{
    this.path = path;
    SIZE = -1;
    WIDTH = width;
    HEIGHT = height;
    pixels = new int[SIZE*SIZE];
    load();
}

private void load()
{
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        image.getRGB(0,0,w,h,pixels,0,w);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.apcompsci.game.graphics.Sprite.<clinit>(Sprite.java:11)
    at com.apcompsci.game.entity.mob.spider.<init>(spider.java:11)
    at com.apcompsci.game.level.SpawnLevel.loadLevel(SpawnLevel.java:36)
    at com.apcompsci.game.level.Level.<init>(Level.java:31)
    at com.apcompsci.game.level.SpawnLevel.<init>(SpawnLevel.java:16)
    at com.apcompsci.game.level.Level.<clinit>(Level.java:19)
    at com.apcompsci.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:49)
    at com.apcompsci.game.Game.main(Game.java:169)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
    at com.apcompsci.game.graphics.SpriteSheet.load(SpriteSheet.java:69)
    at com.apcompsci.game.graphics.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:60)
    at com.apcompsci.game.graphics.SpriteSheet.<clinit>(SpriteSheet.java:17)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Generally this exception is thrown when you are trying to access `array[x]` where `x` is greater or equal arrays length, or is negative. I suspect that since you are trying to use here `[1]` your array has only one element or none. You will get better information if you post code of `Sprite` since this exception is thrown in its 11th line.

Comment: what is the width and height of the image? also what is the size of pixels? I am guessing 0 or 1.

Comment: Why aren't you using a 2D array for your pixel values?  Also, there isn't enough info here for us to help you debug this code.  On top of that, your variable names are a bit confusing.

Comment: He's limited to how the `getRGB()` method wants its target array to look.

Comment: @Pshemo Okay I have updated the post with the sprite.java class.

Comment: @BevynQ it's 95x129. And idk why i'm geting the BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source) error, maybe it can't find the file?

Comment: @CyberneticRwerkGuruOrc I am following a tuturial and will add the sprite.java class momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that the following line in BufferedImage is failing

```
rgbArray[off++] = colorModel.getRGB(raster.getDataElements(x,
                                y,
                                data));
```

rgbArray is the array passed in to the function. It needs to be quite big but the function will initialise it for you if you pass in null.

Try replacing

```
image.getRGB(0,0,w,h,pixels,0,w);
```

with

```
pixels = image.getRGB(0,0,w,h,null,0,w);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should this line:

```
pixels[(x0+y0)*w] = sheet.pixels[(xp+yp)*sheet.WIDTH];
```

be this instead:

```
pixels[x0 + (y0 * w)] = sheet.pixels[xp + (yp * sheet.WIDTH)];
```

Consider WIDTH = w = 5 and HEIGHT = y = 5.  y0 and x0 must be less than 5, so with your code it will attempt to write (4+4)*5 = 40 elements in the pixels array which is initialized to only have 25 elements.